# Move panda df to teradata table: [HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Invalid timestamp

Tags: python, sql, pandas, teradata

I have a df that i want to move to a teradata table. I am using a framework that was discussed on this platform. However I am getting a few errors.
The entire logic behind loading the df to teradata is:

1) If table doesnt exist then create table else skip creation.

2) Start loading the df to the table. (Note i will be passing multiple xlsx files to a df and eventually appending it to the teradata table)

I have written a bteq script to create a table which goes like this:

```
    FROM DBC.TABLES WHERE DATABASENAME = 'abc' AND TABLENAME = 'sample';

.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT <> 0 THEN .GOTO SKIP_CREATION
.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT = 0 THEN .GOTO TABLE_NOT_EXISTS

.LABEL TABLE_NOT_EXISTS 
CREATE TABLE abc.sample ( 
col1 VARCHAR(400) CHARACTER  SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC, 
col2 VARCHAR(400) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
.
.
col23  TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SSZ', 
col24 TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SSZ'
);

.LABEL SKIP_CREATION
.LOGOFF
```

My python code to move the df to teradata is:

```
df=some data frame
host,username,password = 'host','username', "password"
num_of_chunks = 1000
insert_query= "INSERT INTO abc.sample VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="IMC", version="1.0", logConsole=False)
with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system=host, username = username,
                         password=password, driver="Teradata") as session:
    file_exist=session.execute(file=r"Path of the bteq file" ,fileType="bteq",ignoreErrors=[3803])
    schedule_chunks = np.array_split(df, num_of_chunks)

    for i,_ in enumerate(schedule_chunks):

        data = [tuple(x) for x in schedule_chunks[i].to_records(index=False)]

            session.executemany(insert_query, data,batch=True)
```

When I run this i get the following error message:

> DatabaseError: [HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata
>   Database] Invalid timestamp.

Can someone help me with whee am i going wrong? Also need some suggestion if I am writing the bteq script correctly. I want to avoid dropping tables and creating a new one each time.

Comment: What does your timestamp look like?

Comment: The timestamp is in datetime64 format and looks like :

df[ts_cols[dt]] = pd.to_datetime(df[ts_cols[dt]],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Comment: Sorry, wasn't being clear.  Can you post some examples of timestamps you are attempting to insert into your table?

Comment: So the timestamps will end up looking like 2019-09-06 08:00:00, 2019-09-08 04:00:00, 2019-09-10 15:00:00 , in order to replace the blanks where there is no timestamp i have replaced it with a dummy timestamp like 1900-01-01 00:00:00
I have 4 timestamp columns in my df with the same format.

Comment: Those are legit timestamps. Try making the columns varchar.  Then after you run your insert, you can test to see if you have bad timestamps - `select trycast(<your col> as timestamp(0)), <your col> from <your table> where trycast(<your col> as timestamp(0)) is null`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!
So the script ran and it populated the table but i have a timestamp that looks like 2019-09-09T07:30:00.000000000 now. How do i have it loaded as a timestamp datatype and looks like 2019-09-09 07:30:00? 
Also, is there a way i can add a clause in my bteq script which converts all timestamps that look like 1900-01-01 00:00:00 to  a '?' or blanks?

Comment: Note that `fileType="bteq"` just says to ignore all the BTEQ commands (lines that start with a  "."). If you want conditional logic, code it in the python script itself.

Comment: @lea, what is the T in the middle of the timestamp? I know very little about pandas, but that T must be coming out of the to_datetime function. Teradata certainly isn't adding it.

Comment: @Andrew I am guessing its the space between the %d and %H. In a panda dataframe it looks exactly like 2019-09-06 08:00:00 but when i load it in Teradata there is a T inserted between the day and hour.

Comment: @Fred  I did try to change it in python but the code runs without making changes. I use  
ts_cols=[ timestamp cols that i am making changes to]
df [ts_cols[dt] ]=df [ts [dt] ].replace('1900-01-01 00:00:00'," ")
Is there an alternative to it without changing the datatype of the columns as well?

Comment: Yes. It runs the SELECT, ignores the .IF statements, always attempts the CREATE TABLE, gets a 3803 "already exists" error, and you have instructed udaExec to ignore that. In this particular case you'd do just as well to have only the CREATE TABLE in the file or supplied as a string value. With a more complicated BTEQ script, ignoring BTEQ commands could have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to push my dataframe into Teradata successfully. All i did was convert my Timestamp columns in my dataframe from datetime64 to object. Below is the only line of code i added before running the above code

```
df=df.astype(object).where(pd.notnull(df),'')
```